# Updating a integer as a label in swift

Tags: swift, uilabel

I want to change the number value of a label by pressing a button. I used to get errors saying you can't put a number in a string, so, I did string(variable). It now displays the basic number, 1, but when I click it, it doesn't update!

Here is how I set up the variable:
First, I set up the button, to IBAction. Here is the code inside of it:

```
@IBOutlet weak var NumberOfExploits: UILabel!
@IBAction func exploiter(sender: AnyObject) {
    var hacks = 0
    hacks += 1
    NumberOfExploits.text = String(hacks)   
}
```

Can someone help be find out how to get it to change numbers?

Comment: variable += 1 except second line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First:

`let` is used for constants, these can not be changed.
`var` is used for variables.

Second:

Doing plus one is done with `+= 1` or with `= myVariable + 1`

```
var myVariable = 1

myVariable += 1
label.text = string(myVariable)
```

It is important to understand that your variables only live as long as the enclosing class or function is alive. So when you declare a variable, constant inside a function (using `var` `let` is a declaration) it will be be gone when the function is complete. A `UIViewcontroller` is there for as long as you want it to be. So declare things in there that you will need later.

```
import UIKit

// things that live here are at the "global level"


// this is a viewcontroller. It is a page in your app.
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // things that live here are at the "class level"

    var myClassCounter : Int = 0

    // button in interfacebuilder that is connected through an outlet.
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // this is a function that gets called when the view is loaded
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        // this is a function that gets called when the view appeared

    }


    // button function from interface builder
    @IBAction func myButtonIsTouched(sender: AnyObject) {
        // this will be destroyed when the function is done
        var myFunctionCounter = 0
        myFunctionCounter += 1

        // this will be stored at class level
        myClassCounter += 1
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: If the initial assignment of the variable is in the IBAction, as the OP says, the value will only ever be 2.  The variable will need to be declared at class level

Comment: Was leaving some room for discovery

Comment: I did declare it at class level, still doesn't work. Just goes to 2 Help?

Comment: post more code then. Hard too know what is going on.

Comment: I made the edit! However, it says that it need to be peer reviewed.

Comment: don't edit the answer, edit the question. Just add a new block of code. leave the original

Comment: Ok, can you see it now? I changed it in the question.

Comment: I updated my answer to show the different scopes at which things live.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just do

```
label.text = "\\(variable)"
```

which will display the number as string.

Answer (score 0):

Most important declare the variable within the class but outside any function

```
var variable = 1
```

then write the `IBAction` function this way

```
@IBAction func pressButton(sender : UIButton)
{
  label.text = "\(++variable)"
}
```

The syntax `++variable` increments the variable by one.
The syntax `"\(v)"` creates a string of anything which is string representable